# ionic build android command not working

Tags: windows, cordova, sdk, ionic-framework

am new to ionic, I have followed the steps to setup the environment for developing ionic apps from ionicframework site but am stuck on using the `ionic build android` command coz I get this error

`[Error: Please install Android target: "android-17". Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\Program\ Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT
You will require:
   1. "SDK Platform" for android-17
   2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
   3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit     code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2`
 and all these build-tools and platform-tools are installed.what might be the problem please.The `android` command on win cmd is working well coz its openning the sdk manager

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkpRf.png)

Comment: you have `ANDROID_HOME` env var yet?

Comment: yes even the $ android  command opens the sdk manager though the ionic build android  fails

Comment: Have you run `ionic platform add android` before?

Comment: yes my android platform is added well

Comment: I solved this by doing the following.I used phpStorm's terminal when running the `ionic build android` command.I installed apache-maven locally first in another partition **NOT local disk (c)** when I was running the command an error poped-up from another terminal instance that said a scss command was failing and it was being caused by Railsinstaller.I reinstalled the rails,deleted all my earlier projects that i had done `ionic start projectName` then did everything afresh and all worked well.